# Pgadmin и sql запрос

Tags: postgresql, postgresql9.5

У меня есть база в pgadmin. В ней есть 8 таблиц они заполнены. Мне требуется сделать несколько sql запросов на выборку. Вот например:

```
SELECT datas,ploshad,adress,stoimost,flor,kol_vo_room FROM "Object_nedvizimosti" WHERE data > 20.10.2017 and stoimost > 1000000
```

Он мне выдает:

```
ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: ".2017")
LINE 1: ...room FROM "Object_nedvizimosti" WHERE data > 20.10.2017 and …
```

Еще один:

```
SELECT datas,ploshad,adress,stoimost,flor,kol_vo_room FROM "Object_nedvizimosti", "Tip" WHERE Tip.code_tip = Object_nedvizimosti.tip and ploshad = 30
```

Он мне выдает:

```
ОШИБКА:  таблица "tip" отсутствует в предложении FROM
LINE 1: ...l_vo_room FROM "Object_nedvizimosti", "Tip" WHERE Tip.code_t…
```

Не давно начал изучать бд, так что поясните пожалуйста как с этим бороться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В WHERE без кавычек/апострофов можно указывать только значения INT/BIGINT/BOOL.

Строки всё-таки желательно оформлять в кавычках:

```
SELECT datas,ploshad,adress,stoimost,flor,kol_vo_room 
FROM "Object_nedvizimosti" 
WHERE data > '20.10.2017' and stoimost > 1000000
```

Comment: Хорошо, так первый запрос работает. А как быть со вторым?

Comment: во втором запросе у вас две таблицы через запятую после FROM или "Tip" алиас таблицы "Object_nedvizimosti" ? трудно сказать не видя структуры таблицы или их связей между собой, если таблицы две например

Comment: Да таблицы две, в них есть ключи из таблицы "Object_nedvizimosti" в таблицу "Tip" ведет внешний ключ. У меня в объектах храниться тип (1,2,3) в тип (расшифровки) и мне нужно их связать